# Concatenate multiple rows into a single row in LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Is is possible to concatenate multiple rows to a single row?

for example:

```
IEnumerable<sample> sam = new List<sample>()
{
    new sample{ id = 1, name = "sample 1", list = new List<int>{1,5,6}},
    new sample{ id = 2, name = "sample 2", list = new List<int>{2,9}},
    new sample{ id = 3, name = "sample 3", list = new List<int>{8,3,7}},
    new sample{ id = 4, name = "sample 4", list = new List<int>{3,4,8}},
    new sample{ id = 5, name = "sample 5", list = new List<int>{1,5,7}},
    new sample{ id = 6, name = "sample 6", list = new List<int>{6,9,7}}
};
```

output must:

```
{
    new sample { id = 1, name = "sample 1", list = "1,5,6" },
    new sample { id = 2, name = "sample 2", list = "2,9" },
    new sample { id = 3, name = "sample 3", list = "8,3,7" },
    new sample { id = 4, name = "sample 4", list = "3,4,8" },
    new sample { id = 5, name = "sample 5", list = "1,5,7" },
    new sample { id = 6, name = "sample 6", list = "6,9,7" }
};
```

That means from list the new row is now a string.

Comment: You won't be able to return `sample`s, because `list` can be defined as a `List<int>` _or_ a `string`, not both, but otherwise this is pretty trivial LINQ.

Answer (score 8):

Sure:

```
sam.Select(x => new { x.id, x.name, list = String.Join(",", x.list) });
```

Note: The result will be an anonymous type. We can't reuse the `sample` class here, because in that class `list` is of type `List<int>` and not `string`.

If you are stuck with .NET 3.5 or less, use this code instead:

```
sam.Select(x => new
                {
                    x.id, x.name,
                    list = String.Join(",", x.list.Select(y => y.ToString())
                                                  .ToArray())
                });
```

If you want to sort the list before getting the string you need to use this code:

```
sam.Select(x => new
                {
                    x.id, x.name,
                    list = String.Join(",", x.list.OrderBy(y => y))
                });
```

Comment: String.Join takes a `string[]`, not a `List<int>`.

Comment: @Rawling: There are several overloads of `String.Join`. My code uses this one: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992421.aspx

Comment: @abatishchev/Daniel That's great, then. I can't wait to get my hands on 4/4.5.

Comment: @Rawling: Or even starting 3.5 according to the MDSN article Daniel has linked.

Comment: @abatishchev It says "4.5, 4" for me. I did _try_ this code in my 3.5 project before criticizing :)

Comment: @Daniel: So [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992421%28VS.90%29.aspx) is incorrect? ("This page is specific to
Microsoft Visual Studio 2008/.NET Framework **3.5**")

Comment: this one works perfectly, sam.Select(x => new { x.id, x.name, list = String.Join(",", x.list) });
is there a way that the string.join in already sorted? thanks

Comment: @user1120260: result is sorted as input is sorted

Comment: this is not sorted  new sample { id = 3, name = "sample 3", list = "8,3,7" },

Comment: @Daniel: In the bottom it's indeed stated: "Supported in: 4.5, 4". But in the right upper corner there is a "This page is specific to" box where you can choose ver. 3.5. Looks like a bug on MSDN.

Comment: I posted a [bug report](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/libraryfeedback/thread/7fd1ecb3-c8ff-4564-ab92-e5e3cf4c5102) on the MSDN Feedback Forum

Answer (score 0):

As I needed to gather several records in one column (each employee may have many specialties) and then use it in a join, this is the way I resolved:

Having these entities:

1) EMPLOYEEs Entity

```
|EMPLOYEE_ID|

|001        |

|002        |
```

2) EMPLOYEE_SPECIALTIES Entity

```
|EmployeeId|SPECIALTY_CODE

|001       |AAA

|001       |BBB

|002       |DDD

|002       |AAA
```

I needed to gather specialties by employee in one columun:

```
|EmployeeId|SPECIALTY_CODE

|001       |AAA, BBB

|002       |DDD, AAA
```

Solution:

```
var query = from a in context.EMPLOYEE_SPECIALTIES.ToList()
            group a by a.EMPLOYEE_ID into g
            select new 
            {
                EmployeeId = g.Key,
                SpecialtyCode = string.Join(",", g.Select(x =>  
                x.SPECIALTY_CODE))
            };

var query2 = (from a in query
              join b in context.EMPLOYEEs on a.EmployeeId equals b.EMPLOYEE_ID
              select new EmployeeSpecialtyArea
              {
                  EmployeeId = b.EMPLOYEE_ID,
                  LastName = b.LAST_NAME,
                  SpecialtyCode = a.SpecialtyCode
              });

ViewBag.EmployeeSpecialtyArea = query2;
```

I hope this may help someone!